# Touch doesn't scale according to the changed resolution on Android Q/10

Tags: touchscreen, android-10, screen-resolution

I have an android device with a resolution of 1080px2160p and an aspect ratio of 18:9. I downloaded a resolution changing app from play store by the name of DPI Changer. It changes the device resolution and DPI to whatever values you input. I have tried changing resolution to 1080x1920, 1080x1080 and 720x1280. The resolution changes without any issues but the touch is not scaling properly according to the resolution [ the touch issue happens only when the device is in reverse landscape mode ]. There's a distance of 120px between the actual area touched and the area registered by the device. I have tried several different apps but all of them give the same issue. I am rooted and willing to try anything that would fix the problem.

Comment: You may need to select a resolution that has the same aspect ratio as your physical screen. I would contact the authors of the used apps and ask kindly if resolutions based on the current aspect ration can be added to the app.

Comment: I did email the developer and asked him. He's yet to respond. I also learnt that changing resolution isn't an issue with device running Oreo or lower version. It seems Google added some kind of hardware check in place where the resolution area is cross checked with physical area.